# Retrieve and Modify the @ConfigurationContext programmatically via code?

Tags: spring

How to Retrieve and Modify the @ConfigurationContext programmatically via code ?

I have a default configuration where it contains valid xml files.

Now i need to add an invalid configuration for a particular test case and test the same.

How to override, retrieve and modify the @ConfigurationContext programmatically via code ?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Comment: Isn't it easier and better if you just create a new context file and then annotate the test class with `@ContextConfiguration("classpath:new-context-file.xml")`? At least with JUnit this is the way

Comment: But it will fail the entire test class and i would like to fail a test case and log the errors. I need to create assert statements for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am assuming you are using JUnit since you didn't comment differently in your reply to my comment.
I think what you are trying to do does not make lot of sense, in my opinion it is still better to create a dedicated test class for your not-working configuration in order to be able to do more than one test. However:

1. annotate your test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/working-context.xml"})`. In this way you can retrieve the configuration context in two ways: first, you can simply declare a field `@Inject ApplicationContext context` which will contain the working context. Or, you make your test class `implements ApplicationContextAware` and then write a `public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext applicationContext)`. I would go for the second one since it will come in hand for changing the context programmatically.
2. write a `not-working-context.xml` and place it in your classpath
3. in the test method you want to fail, reload the application context with `context = setApplicationContext(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("not-working-context.xml"));` and test all the errors you like.
4. though it is not good practice to stand on test case order, make sure your failing test will be executed as the last one (tests are executing alphabetically) so you don't have to reload the working context in the other tests.

In the end your test class will look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/working-context.xml"})
public class TestClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private ApplicationContext context;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context){
    this.context = context;
  }

  //Other tests

  @Test
  public void zFailingTest() {
    context = setApplicationContext(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("not-working-context.xml"));
    //your test
  }
}
```

Comment: When i load the invalid dozer mapping.xml where the class names are not correct and instead of loading successfully it throws the error Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mappings'. what might be the wrong ? The Xml header looks like below <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net schema/beanmapping.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

Comment: You are trying (correct me if I guessed wrong) to test the behavior when Spring configuration file is wrong in the sense of missing class, typos, etc. BUT. Basically, Spring is a framework which will do lot of work (instantiation, IoC, etc) before being ready for you to use. You cannot unit test this kind of stuff because all the relative work is done before the environment is made available to you, so all the fails cause the environment to be shut down. Start reading [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html)